# Extract the rolling period return from a timeseries

Tags: time-series

For example, let ts be defined as:

```
ts= FinancialData["SBUX", "Close", {{2013, 1, 1}, {2013, 12, 1}}]
```

How can I, for example, from ts a new timeseries with the rolling values #[[n+12]]/#[[n]]-1 with the associated dates be for the n+12 date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$Version

(* "13.1.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 16, 2022)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

ts = FinancialData["SBUX", "Close", {{2013, 1, 1}, {2013, 12, 1}}];

{dates, close} = Transpose[ts // Normal];

ts2 = TimeSeries[
   Transpose[{dates[[13 ;;]], close[[13 ;;]]/close[[;; -13]] - 1}]];

DateListPlot[ts2]
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`MovingMap`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MovingMap.html).

`MovingMap` width specification is zero based so with `ts` in OP then

```
tsReturns = MovingMap[Last@#Values/First@#Values - 1 &, ts, 12]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Note that the series starts on 14 Jan which is 13 days after 2 Jan as desired since width spec is zero based.

```
DateListPlot[tsReturns, PlotTheme -> "Detailed"]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Hope this helps.

Comment: I never figured out the correct syntax for MovingMap.  Thank you.